# how can i set the time in digital clock

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to build an android application, this application allow the users to answer some questions.
For every question, User have to answer it in `360 seconds`, so I want to make a digital clock starts from `360secons` and then down to `0 seconds`

I read that I can't set time on digital clock , is it so?

or I have to use Chronometer?

this is my digital clock

```
DigitalClock timer;
public void init(){
timer=(DigitalClock)findViewById(R.id.dcTimer);
}
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: i just added code because stackoverflow says that my question is not with a good quality :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) instead.

That link also shows you how to update a `TextView` every 1 second.

Just change `new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000)` so the first parameter is `360000` instead of `30000` and that will give you a good start to your code.

**EDIT** : You need to import `android.os.CountDownTimer` and the code example I referred to is below. Good luck.

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: would you give me another website , that is forbidden to my country

Comment: What country are you in? That link is to the official Android Developers website why would it be forbidden?.

Comment: i am in Syria ,and the official android website is forbidden

Comment: @Totti : See my edit. I'd advise you search other stackoverflow questions for examples of `CountDownTimer` if the official Android Developers site is not accessible to you.

Comment: @Totti : Glad to help. The second parameter of `1000` is 1000 milliseconds (1 second) and controls how often `onTick(...)` is called. Hopefully that example is enough the get you started.

Comment: you give me the activity ,would you give me the xml definition , thank you

Comment: yes it helps me , and exactly what i want , i understand it , it is easy and helpfull

Comment: thank you i understant it , there is no xml definition for count down timer , but i have to build a text view and put the remaining time in it every tick  , thank you man

Comment: @Totti : Yes, just a a simple XML layout with a `TextView` will get you started and then add other views for questions and answer buttons.